# selecting complex query into an exsiting column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, one column of which is VERY dependant on a bunch of other tables

i can't alter the table, and i can't change the name of the parameter that is used

this is my query :

```
select *,(select sum(itemQuantity*(select itemPrice from Items where 
Items.itemID=OrderItems.itemID)) from OrderItems 
where OrderItems.orderNumber=Orders.orderNumber) as orderValue,
(select sum(itemQuantity) from OrderItems where OrderItems.orderNumber=Orders.orderNumber)
as orderItemQuantity from Orders  WHERE Orders.customerId =1 AND Orders.beenSupplied =1
```

and this is the result of this query:

[image]

as you can see, i have the column "orderValue" twice 
the first orderValue is the original column from the Orders table, and the second orderValue is from the "as" clause in the query

how do i merge the two columns and have the output of the query in it, and not the 0 that constantly gets inserted ?

EDIT:
table structures:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well it's subquery madness for sure can you provide us with an table structure and example data on sqlfiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: "have the output of the query in it" What does this mean?

Comment: meaning i have only one column named "orderValue" with the output of the query - and i can't delete the first orderValue, nor can i change the variable that receives the output of this column

Comment: @RaymondNijland i posted the table structures,

Comment: @RaymondNijland The output of the query is correct, the only problem is that i am left with 2 columns named "orderValue" and i want only one column, how do i make that happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `SELECT *`, explicitly list the columns (from your `Orders` table) that you wish to select.

You can also avoid using (the highly inefficient) correlated subqueries by joining the tables in the outermost query and then grouping each order.

```
SELECT   Orders.orderNumber,
         Orders.customerId,
         Orders.orderDate,
         Orders.beenSupplied,
         Orders.purchaseDate,
         SUM(OrderItems.itemQuantity * Items.itemPrice) AS orderValue,
         SUM(OrderItems.itemQuantity)                   AS orderItemQuantity
FROM     Orders
    JOIN OrderItems USING (orderNumber)
    JOIN Items      USING (itemID)
WHERE    Orders.customerId   = 1
     AND Orders.beenSupplied = 1
GROUP BY Orders.orderNumber
```

Comment: i ran your query, and i ran my query modified according to your select clause - mysql said that your query took 0.0030 seconds, and my query took 0.0010 seconds. Why did this happen ? if you say that join variant of the query is more efficient

Comment: @LenaBru: It's more a question of how well they can scale as the tables grow in size.  How many records does each table contain at present?  What indexes are defined?  Is it possible that the results of your query was returned from cache?